# Describe the tangent bundle of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ explicitly as a subset of $M(n,\mathbb{R})\times M(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: differential-geometry

The full problem states as follows:

Let $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ be the space of $n\times n$ matrices. We assume that $n\geq 2$. Let $SL(n,\mathbb{R})=\{A\in M(n, \mathbb{R}): \det A=1\}$.

1. Show that $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is an $(n^2-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $M(n, \mathbb{R})$. - I was able to show this by using  the regular value theorem.
2. Describe the tangent space to $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ at the identity matrix $I_n$ explicitly as a linear subspace of $M(n, \mathbb{R})$. - I was able to show that the the tangent space is the kernel of $d\det_I$, although I'm not 100% sure that I'm correct.
3. Describe the tangent bundle of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ explicitly as a subset of $M(n,\mathbb{R})\times M(n,\mathbb{R})$. - I'm not sure where to begin with this problem. Could anyone give me some hint? Much appreciated!

Comment: Where did the $x$ come from? Why isn’t it just $n?$

Comment: My apologies, that was a typo.

Comment: You already know that $T_I{\rm SL}(n,\Bbb R) = \ker {\rm d}(\det)_I$, now show that ${\rm d}(\det)_I = {\rm tr}$. For the last item, $T_A{\rm SL}(n,\Bbb  R) = \{  AB \mid B\in T_I{\rm SL}(n,\Bbb R) \}$.